# Why Label is showing only First few characters in Custom message box?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

i'm creating a custom message box in c#.net.

so, i'm placing a "Label" and setting its "text" property equal to message forwarded through the Show() function.

the code looks like this -----

```
public static void main(string msg)
{
   Label txt=new Label();
   txt.Text=msg;
   txt.Location = new Point((m.Width/2-txt.Width/2), 100);
   m.controls.Add(txt);     

// here m is object of MsgBox
}

// calling of MsgBox is below

   MsgBox.Show("This is a Line of Message to Show");
```

**PROBLEM**
The MsgBox is only showing the message

"This is a Line"

And how to place this label in center (horizontally and vertically)
In message box.

So please, if you can help me to solve this problem

Comment: Have you set AutoSize on the label to true?

Comment: Check properties of MsgBox button. you will find answer .OR You have to increase Label's width by dragging horizontally.